# How do I get all first elements of python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I used dictionaries the first time and I can't figure out how to get all first elements of a dictionary. The picture shows an example of my problem. I want to get the brand names, not "brand0, brand1" etc.

```
thisdict = {
    "brand0": ("Ford", "green_car"),
    "brand1": ("Audi", "yellow_car"),
    "brand2": ("Porsche", "red_car")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you put "How do I get all first elements of python dictionary?" into a search engine, did any useful results come up?

Comment: what have you tried so far? take a look at the official docs for dictionaries!: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Copy-and-paste the code directly into the question. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use several aproaches to this problem but the easiest is probably this

```py
firstItems = [value[0] for value in thisdict.values()]
```

this works the same as

```py
firstItems = []
for value in thisdict.values():
    firstItems.append(value[0])
```